# Adobe has discontinued PhoneGap Build and ended investment in PhoneGap and Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, adobe, phonegap

Adobe has discontinued PhoneGap Build and ended investment in PhoneGap and Apache Cordova.
This website is no longer being updated. Find out more details here
Your application has updated and a build has been queued

**Will be able to crete our existitng apps**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move to an alternative service. There are several out there, including VoltBuilder, Ionic and Monica.

(Disclosure: I'm on the VoltBuilder Dev team)

Comment: Can you explain the advantaes of VoltBuilder? I didn't know it and I googled it, it seems quite interesting

Comment: further, can I compile the app for the new Huaweii store with VoltBuilder?

Comment: There is a chart comparing PhoneGap to VoltBuilder here: https://volt.build/about/. VoltBuilder produces standard Android apk executables. If the Huaweii store can handle them, you should be fine. Feel free to contact us directly with more questions!

Comment: I just write an email to the support email address, I'm trying to convert my project but I have some troubles